# My hamburguer menu disappears when clicking on it's items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Recently I uploaded my website online on Github and it came out with some display problems.

I have an Hamburguer menu icon (.toggle - in my code) for widths less than 1210px. When I click in the icon it works fine, displaying the submenu with the items, but when I click in the home button the main page loses the menu icon. I don´t know why.

I've tested it previously before it became public, and it was working fine.

The same thing happens when I click on the a-tower  or muda items and then backwards to home, again the icon disappears.

I have already tried to research about that error in specific but didn´t find one particularly similar.

html:

```
    <div class="header">
        <div class="menu-one">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src=".\logo_final.png">
                <div class="lettering">
                    <h6><span class="bolder">F</span>ÁTIMA<span class="bolder">C</span>RISTÓVÃO <span class="smaller">by KELLER WILLIAMS</span></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class= "toggle">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul id="menu-two" class="hide">
            <li class="item">
                <a href="./index.html" >Home</a> 
            </li>
            <li class="item" id="proj">
                <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="options">
                <a href="./Atower.html" >A-Tower</a>
            </li>
            <li class="options">
                <a href="./muda.html">Muda</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#About-Me">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#Contact" >Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.header {
background-color: rgb(235, 223, 201);
z-index: 100;
top: 0px;
margin: 0 auto;
max-height: 5rem;
position: fixed;
border-bottom-style: double;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
width: 100%
}

.menu-one {
display: flex
}

.logo {
display: flex;
}

.logo img { 
height: 100%
}

.lettering  {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: flex-end;
padding-left: 1%;
}

h6 {
margin-bottom: 1.7%;
font-family: 'calibri';
font-weight: lighter;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
font-size: 0.8em;
}

h6 .bolder {
font-weight: bold;
}

h6 .smaller {
font-weight: lighter;
}

.toggle {
display: none;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 20px;
color: black
}

#menu-two{
display: flex;
}

.hide {
 display: none;
}

li {
list-style: none;
padding: 1em
}    


@media only screen  and (max-width: 1210px) {



#menu-two {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
  }

#proj {
    display: none;
}

#menu-two.visible {
    opacity: 0.9;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.hide {
    background-color: rgb(245, 243, 229);
    opacity: 0.95;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.options {
    display: block;
}

.menu-one {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%
}
.toggle{
    display: initial;
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    transform: translate(-10px);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle span {
    position: relative;
    width: 36px;
    height: 4px;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.toggle span:nth-child(1) {
    transform-origin: left;

}

.toggle span:nth-child(2) {
    transform-origin: center;
}

.toggle span:nth-child(3) {
    transform-origin: left;
}

.toggle.active span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    left: 2px;
}

.toggle.active span:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
    right: 3px;
}

.toggle.active span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: scaleX(0);
}

}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
$('.toggle, .item').on('click', function() {
    $('.toggle').toggleClass('active');
    $('#menu-two').toggleClass('visible')
}) 

$('.active').on('click', function() {
    $('.toggle').fadeToggle()
})

})
```

Note: when I resize my browser in my desktop, when it gets smaller, between 870px and 560px the menu burguer stays on the right, and disappears during these dimensions periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your site, it's not a jquery issue. The hamburger icons disappear because of the logo property "flex".

Replace this CSS on your stylesheet, I will fix your issue.

`.logo {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}`

when your hamburger menu appears, it's got CSS `display: block` property so it failed to counter the `display: flex`.

Let me know Please.

Comment: So I tried this, but the problem mantains, 

Speaking clearly, I have more media queries: max-width: 665px, max-width: 559px, min-width: 560px and max-width: 870px, min-width: 500px and max-width: 559px.

None of this media queries is directly related with the header but when i'm in mobile version click on the a-tower and then backwards to index my icon only appears when I resize the screen to exactly 560px.

Comment: I can see that you implement `flex:1` its working fine, just a small thing add  `width: calc(100% - 50px)` to the `.logo` class and problem will be solved. you won't have to add the CSS to the other media queries. The problem is logo got the property `display:flex` so whenever page refreshes flex takes the 100% width, pushing the manu icon to the top right.

Comment: Happy to help @PedroCris

Answer (score 0):

A couple things are going on here. First, some of the links are redirecting you to a new page, without the header code. Second, you have your first click event set up to respond to `.toggle` and `.item`. `.item` refers to your menu items, so you want to remove that target.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('.toggle').toggleClass('active');
    $('#menu-two').toggleClass('visible')
  })

  $('.active').on('click', function() {
    $('.toggle').fadeToggle()
  })


   $('ul#menu-two > li > a').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1210px) {
  #menu-two {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
  }
  #proj {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu-two.visible {
    opacity: 0.9;
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
  .hide {
    background-color: rgb(245, 243, 229);
    opacity: 0.95;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .options {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-one {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%
  }
  .toggle {
    display: initial;
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    transform: translate(-10px);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .toggle span {
    position: relative;
    width: 36px;
    height: 4px;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .toggle span:nth-child(1) {
    transform-origin: left;
  }
  .toggle span:nth-child(2) {
    transform-origin: center;
  }
  .toggle span:nth-child(3) {
    transform-origin: left;
  }
  .toggle.active span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    left: 2px;
  }
  .toggle.active span:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
    right: 3px;
  }
  .toggle.active span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="menu-one">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src=".\logo_final.png">
      <div class="lettering">
        <h6><span class="bolder">F</span>ÁTIMA<span class="bolder">C</span>RISTÓVÃO <span class="smaller">by KELLER WILLIAMS</span></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul id="menu-two" class="hide">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="proj">
      <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li class="options">
      <a href="./Atower.html">A-Tower</a>
    </li>
    <li class="options">
      <a href="./muda.html">Muda</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#About-Me">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: but when I click in the items nothing happens

Comment: @PedroCris see the last few lines in the JavaScript code. I added an `e.preventDefault()` for testing purposes.

Comment: Yes I saw it, so is it blocking the anchor elements from redirecting it to the pages?

Comment: @PedroCris Yeah. It prevents their default action, which is that. Just comment it out or remove it to have them redirect.

Comment: I´ve made that changes, but when I click in the first 3 items (home, a-tower, muda), the menu icon goes right and hides from my current screen width, for instance, if my width is 330px the menu goes right, and i need to resize to 560 px to see the icon again, it seems some issue related with css.